# google sheets sidebar text area to server side script

Tags: javascript, html, sidebar

I have a function that will send emails from google sheets.  I would like to compose the email subject and body in the sidebar option in google sheets hit send and have the subject and body past as variables to the server side function to send the emails.

I hope I was able to clearly explain what I am asking.  I have VERY little programming knowledge so please excuse me.  I have my current coding below and any improvements or fixes would be greatly appreciated.

```
    function onOpen() {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.createMenu('Email')
          .addItem('Remaining Email Quota', 'emailQuota')
          .addSeparator()
          .addItem('Send Email', 'sideBar')
          .addToUi();
    }

function sendEmail(formSubject,formBody){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var sheet = app.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

    for (var i = 5; i <=lastRow;i++){

    var currentEmail = sheet.getRange(i,4).getValue();
    var emailConfirm = sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue();

    if(emailConfirm == "Yes"){
    if(currentEmail !=""){
       MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, formSubject, formBody);
       }

  } 
    }

}

    function sideBar(){
      var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sideBarEmail')
          .setTitle('Email Subject & Body').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
          .setWidth(400);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
          .showSidebar(html);   
    }
```

HTML Portion Below__________________________________________

```
>     <base target="_top">
>     <script>
>      function onSuccessSubject(getSubject){   var subject = document.getElementById("formSubject");    }
>       google.script.run.sendEmail();
> 
> </script>   </head>   <body>
> 
> 
> <form>
> 
> <form id="formSubject">
>     <p> Subject:<br>   <input type="text" name="subject" size="36"> </p>
>     </form>
> 
> <p> Body:<br> <textarea name="body" rows="15"
> cols="37"style="Left"></textarea> </p>
> 
> <input type="button" value="Send" onclick =
> "google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessSubject).getSubject();"/>
> 
> <input type="button" value="Cancle" onclick="google.script.run
>         .withSuccessHandler(showConfirmation(document.getElementById('subject').value))
>         .processData(document.getElementById('subject').value)" />
> 
> </form>
>     </body>
```